# Google search result returns number of result with time fraction—what does it represent?

Tags: google-search

When we search something on Google it returns results with a light colored text at the top, like *About 1,270,000,000 results (0.29 seconds)*.

What does it represent and what is Google’s logic behind this?

Comment: It means that about 1,270,000,000 results were found and that search took 0.29 seconds. Which part is unclear to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply...

1. The total number of matches it found &
2. How long it took to find them.

You could think of it as a “bragging device”—“Look how many results I managed to find & how quickly I did it.”

SQL [& presumably other databases] automatically provide those figures for any query; for instance, from my own database… *Showing rows 0 - 3 (4 total, Query took 0.0007 sec)*.